# Android bind obb error?

Tags: mount, root-access

So, I am on Android 4.2.2
I have the obb file in /storage/extSdCard/obb/ending directory
And want it binded in /sdcard/Android/obb/starting directory

So, I run in my busybox

```
#!/system/bin/sh
mount -o bind /storage/extSdCard/obb/ending/ /sdcard/Android/obb/starting/
```

But, I do not know why, when I run

```
ls /sdcard/Android/obb/starting
```

I get no output. Why? Any ideas?
Many thanks in advance! :)

EDIT: My external sd is fat32. Tried it on my second partition which is ext2 but still no luck

Comment: Please hover on your [android] tag for important information.

Comment: @fixer1234 I am on mobile and it gets my on an Android feed